# How to use keras for XOR

Tags: python, neural-network, xor, keras

I want to practice keras by code a xor, but the result is not right, the followed is my code, thanks for everybody to help me.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense,Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()# two layers
model.add(Dense(input_dim=2,output_dim=4,init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(input_dim=4,output_dim=1,init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
sgd = SGD(l2=0.0,lr=0.05, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.11, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=sgd)
print "begin to train"
list1 = [1,1]
label1 = [0]
list2 = [1,0]
label2 = [1]
list3 = [0,0]
label3 = [0]
list4 = [0,1]
label4 = [1] 
train_data = np.array((list1,list2,list3,list4)) #four samples for epoch = 1000
label = np.array((label1,label2,label3,label4))

model.fit(train_data,label,nb_epoch = 1000,batch_size = 4,verbose = 1,shuffle=True,show_accuracy = True)
list_test = [0,1]
test = np.array((list_test,list1))
classes = model.predict(test)
print classes
```

> Output

```
[[ 0.31851079] [ 0.34130159]] [[ 0.49635666] [0.51274764]]
```

Comment: What does "not right" mean? What result do you get? What would you expect?

Comment: thanks, i want to get the list classes = [a,b],a approach to 1,b approach to 0,but the truth is that a,b just like a random,there are two results:[[ 0.31851079]
 [ 0.34130159]]         [[ 0.49635666]
 [ 0.51274764]]

Comment: Please integrate this into your question. That way we don't have to reproduce your exercise to know what's wrong...

Answer (score 2):

If I increase the number of epochs in your code to 50000 it does often converge to the right answer for me, just takes a little while :)

It does often get stuck, though. I get better convergence properties if I change your loss function to 'mean_squared_error', which is a smoother function.

I get still faster convergence if I use the Adam or RMSProp optimizers. My final compile line, which works:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
...
model.fit(train_data, label, nb_epoch = 10000,batch_size = 4,verbose = 1,shuffle=True,show_accuracy = True)
```

Comment: 4 hyper parameter is being fitted to 4 (data point, labels). An XOR operator is not being learned, it is being overfitted.

Comment: Yep that's Correct @ J.Down

Answer (score 1):

I used a single hidden layer with 4 hidden nodes, and it almost always converges to the right answer within 500 epochs.  I used sigmoid activations.

Comment: That would be overfitting?

Comment: You can't overfit XOR, there is no noise/variance error!

Answer (score 1):

**XOR training with Keras**

Below, the minimal neuron network architecture required to learn XOR which should be a (2,2,1) network. In fact, if maths shows that the (2,2,1) network can solve the XOR problem, but maths doesn't show that the (2,2,1) network is easy to train. It could sometimes takes a lot of epochs (iterations) or does not converge to the global minimum. That said, I've got easily good results with (2,3,1) or (2,4,1) network architectures.

The problem seems to be related to the existence of many local minima. Look at this 1998 paper, «[Learning XOR: exploring the space of a classic problem](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/techreps/pdf/TR148.pdf)» by Richard Bland. Furthermore weights initialization with random number between 0.5 and 1.0 helps to converge.

It works fine with Keras or TensorFlow using loss function 'mean_squared_error', sigmoid activation and Adam optimizer. Even with pretty good hyperparameters, I observed that the learned XOR model is trapped in a local minimum about 15% of the time.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
import numpy as np 

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

def initialize_weights(shape, dtype=None):
    return np.random.normal(loc = 0.75, scale = 1e-2, size = shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, 
                activation='sigmoid', 
                kernel_initializer=initialize_weights, 
                input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("*** Training... ***")

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=4, epochs=10000, verbose=0)

print("*** Training done! ***")

print("*** Model prediction on [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] ***")

# print(model.predict_proba(X))
print(model.predict([X])
```

*** Training... ***

*** Training done! ***

*** Model prediction on [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] ***

[[0.08662204]
[0.9235283 ]
[0.92356336]
[0.06672956]]

Comment: `from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense` and `predict_proba` doesn't seem to exist on `Sequential` any longer.