# Does the input for LSTM in NLP need to be the same length?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, lstm

What is the input for the problem of text sentiment classification using LSTM?

Does each sentence need to be the same lenght? Or no?

Can anyone explain it step by step using two sentence example?

Example:

a. I like this book.
b. I do not like this book.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, input sequence must be at the same length. The solution in most cases for different lengths of inputs is padding with zero to a fixed length. I recommend you to read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536182/testing-the-keras-sentiment-classification-with-model-predict/34154972#34154972) and read sections (7) and (8) for your question.

The entire process is explained in the attached link and you can use it for your example to understand it.